# ahah in drupal not working at all

Tags: drupal, ahah

For some reason the ahah functionality stopped working after a theme upgrade. I tried the simplest examples of ahah and it doesn't work. I also downloaded ahah-helper module, and even the example there doesn't work.

I copied exactly every code that's in this link :
http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/getting-going-ahah-and-drupal-6

when I submit a ahah form - the page loads again without any other affects (the form doesn't really gets submitted, form_submit not invoked).

i have no idea where to start looking for a solution....

I'm using drupal 6.

Comment: If the functionality stopped after a theme upgrade, you should check the changes done with that upgrade. Main candidates to look at would be changes in the themes JavaScript files/code.

Comment: what does a working ahah javascript code should look like? meaning, what should i look for in the js files?

Comment: @MosheShaham Is this a contrib theme? If so, which one and which version?

Comment: @MosheShaham: Does your custom theme load a separate version of jQuery to the one included with Drupal core?

Comment: @Clive:  Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem! Really really appreciate it. How can I grant you the 50 points?

Comment: @MosheShaham: happy to help I've been caught out by that a few times :) I'll turn the comment into a more useful answer and post it below, I think you'll be able to award the points then :)

Comment: I am not a Drupal expert but still I think this article would b helpful for others in this regard http://www.mindyourcode.com/php/adding-dynamic-form-elements-using-ahah-in-apply-for-for-role-module/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have a second version of jquery loaded by your theme. This is either causing a conflict between jquery versions or introducing a jquery library that is incompatible with Drupal's core js.

As far as I'm aware the latest version of jquery that works with Drupal 6 is 1.3.2, which you can install using the [jQuery update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update). I've read reports of people getting v1.4 and even v1.5 to work but at the cost of some core functionality like AHAH